# Android espresso- dismis snackbar (swipeRight) is not working on api 33

Tags: android-espresso

Im tring to dismiss Snackbare using this code:

```
 onView(withId(R.id.snackbar_text))
.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            .perform(swipeRight())
```

It works on all APIs untill API 33.
on API 33 the test move to the next line of code but the snack bar still appears on the screen.

Any idea how to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

After bumping espresso version to the latest alpha release (`3.5.0-alpha07`), as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73422446/7973565), it started to work