# Espresso swipeUp(), swipeDown() etc. No longer working on API 33+ (Android 13)

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-espresso, android-testing

So I am running instrumented tests with my app targeting API 33 (Android 13). I noticed some tests were failing due to the espresso swipe functions not doing their job.

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.content)).perform(swipeUp())
```

The test does not fail on this call, but later because my test depends on the action to evaluate the UI.

For reference, this is the code in the Espresso swipeUp function:

```
public static ViewAction swipeUp() {
return actionWithAssertions(
    new GeneralSwipeAction(
        Swipe.FAST,
        GeneralLocation.translate(GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_CENTER, 0, -EDGE_FUZZ_FACTOR),
        GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER,
        Press.FINGER));
```

}

I am using Espresso 3.3.0. Everything works fine until testing on an API 33 emulator.

Has anyone else had this problem, and if not is there a workaround?

Answer (score 10):

I've bumped espresso version to the latest alpha version (`3.5.0-alpha07`) and seems like it fixed the issue

Comment: Espresso above 3.3.0 for me has never worked, I never manage to get any tests to run :(

Comment: @SeanBlahovici Did you manage to get your tests to run ? I'm having the same problem upgrading from 3.4.0 to 3.5.0.

Comment: @ShivamVerma I figured out why Espresso above 3.3.0 wasn't working for me. I had to exclude protobuf-lite from espresso contrib, like so:

androidTestImplementation(Deps.espressoContrib) {
        exclude module: "protobuf-lite"
    }

Comment: 3.4 -> 3.5 worked for me.

Comment: Does anyone have a link that Espresso bug?

Answer (score 5):

Latest regular version of espresso (3.5.0) has fixed this bug and currently, I don't have any other issues.

Comment: Could you please share a link to that bug?